# How to add accordian items dynamically?

Tags: extjs

I have view like this :

```
Ext.define('Example.demo.CycleInfo', {

    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    requires:[
            'Ext.layout.container.Accordion'
    ],
    xtype: 'cycleinfo',

    title: 'All Data',


    defaults: {
        frame: true,
        bodyPadding: 5
    },

     initComponent: function() {
        data = this.data
        Ext.apply(this, {
            items: [{
                    layout: 'accordion',
                    frame: true,
                    bodyPadding: 5,
                    items: [{
                        xtype:'structure'
                    },
                    {
                    title: 'Requests',
                    html: 'Empty'
                    }]
            }]
        });
        this.callParent();
     }

});
```

Here there are two accordian (one included item and other Requests) they are static .. I want based on this.data value(contains length) It should have accordian in the inner items. How should I do it.

Comment: How should I add the items dynamically that should be in accordian layout?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add more panels to your main container with `accordion` layout, this should work:

```
Ext.define('Example.demo.CycleInfo', {

        extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
        requires:[
            'Ext.layout.container.Accordion'
        ],
        xtype: 'cycleinfo',

        title: 'All Data',


        defaults: {
            frame: true,
            bodyPadding: 5
        },

        initComponent: function() {
            me = this;
            Ext.apply(me, {
                items: [{
                    layout: 'accordion',
                    frame: true,
                    bodyPadding: 5,
                    items: [{
                        title: 'Testing...',
                        html: 'This is a test panel'
                    },{
                        title: 'Requests',
                        html: 'Empty'
                    }]
                }],
                dockedItems: [{
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    dock: 'top',
                    ui: 'footer',
                    items: ['->',{
                        text: 'Add panel',
                        handler: function() {
                            this.up().up().down('panel').add({
                                title: 'New Panel',
                                html : 'New Content'
                            })
                        }
                    }]
                }]
            });
            this.callParent();
        }

    });

    Ext.create('Example.demo.CycleInfo',{
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        width: 500,
        height: 500
    });
```

Comment: My requirement is different ... I want that on the basis of data( length) Items should be added dynamically under accordian layout

Comment: can you post a sample of this data?

Comment: The value coming in data is 2(Integer).

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.define('CycleInfo', {

  extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
  requires:[
        'Ext.layout.container.Accordion'
  ],
  xtype: 'cycleinfo',

  title: 'All Data',
  width : 400,
  height : 500,

  defaults: {
    frame: true,
    bodyPadding: 5
  },
  layout: 'accordion',
  initComponent: function() {
    this.tbar = [{
        text : 'Add Panel To Accordion',
        handler : function(){
            this.add({
                xtype:'panel',
                html: 343434
            });
        },
        scope:this
      }];
      this.callParent();
  }

 });

Ext.create('CycleInfo',{renderTo:Ext.getBody()});

In your case you must change **xtype** in initComponent all is well
```